# Weird errors, JAVAFX FXML

Tags: javafx

Here is my code, I will put //and the error before each bit that causes an error.

```
  @Override
public void//Syntax error on token "void", @ expected start(Stage//Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s) stage) throws//Syntax error on token "throws", interface expected Exception {
   Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("fxml_example.fxml"));

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 275);

    stage.setTitle("FXML Welcome");//Syntax error on token ";", @ expected
    stage.setScene(scene);//Syntax error on token ";", @ expected
    stage.show()//Syntax error, insert ")" to complete MethodDeclaration;
}
```

Comment: Could you please post your code without the messages? It's extremely hard to determine where your comments end and your code continues. Also perhaps the code before your snippet is the cause of the error. Please incude it too...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be missing the opening part of the `start method.

```
@Override
public void start(Stage stage) {
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("fxml_example.fxml"));
    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 275);
    stage.setTitle("FXML Welcome");//Syntax error on token ";", @ expected
    stage.setScene(scene);//Syntax error on token ";", @ expected
    stage.show();//You are missing semi-colon here.
}
```